# OCaml function calls happening in wrong order

Tags: ocaml

Right, so this is an odd problem that really took me by surprise. Basically, I'm working on a build system that gives you the option of running shell commands before and after the main build. To execute these commands I'm just using `Sys.command`. The problem is that whenever I use that function it changes the order in which functions are called. For example:

```
Sys.command "echo 'Hi!'";
Printf.printf "second\n";
Sys.command "echo 'Bye!'"
```

outputs

```
Hi!
Bye!
second
```

from both the REPL and compiled executables. However, if I use any other function it seems to work fine. Interestingly, if I define a function to call `Sys.command` it still executes in the wrong order. I've tested this on both 4.02.1 running on GNU/Linux and 4.01.0 in Cygwin and get the same behavior on both. As far as I am aware the `;` does not affect call order. Am I missing something here?

Comment: That's the correct order. What were you expecting?

Comment: Well, I would have expected it to run in in the order the functions were called in ("Hi!" -> "..." -> "Bye"). Why would it not call the functions from first to last?

Comment: Well in your current example you're echoing Hi, then a new line, then a Bye, which is the output. If you wanted an extra space you need 2 new line characters. So you should edit your example if you're trying to show something else...

Comment: @matrixanomaly I've edited it to show more clearly what I mean. The last function run is always `Printf.printf`, even though it comes second in sequential order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a buffering problem.

Try this:

```
Sys.command "echo 'Hi!'";
Printf.printf "second\n%!";
Sys.command "echo 'Bye!'"
```

The `%!` specifier says to flush the buffer at that point.

Because it's a mixed paradigm language (with side effects), OCaml expressions are executed in a predictable order. You can depend on this. If things seem to be executed out of order, there is something else going on.

(As a side comment, note that order of evaluation of parameters to a function is not constrained.)