# The strange order of code execution in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

Recently, I began to study OCaml. I found a strange thing as a result program execution. Example is a part of TicTacToe console game.
This code:

```
let move pl arr =  
  let () = Printf.printf "Player %i, enter two numbers: \n" pl in
  let x1 = Scanf.scanf "%i\n" (fun n -> n) in
  let y1 = Scanf.scanf "%i\n" (fun n -> n) in
  if (pl=1) then Array.set arr.(x1) y1 "X"
            else Array.set arr.(x1) y1 "O"
  ;;
```

Give such strange result:

```
root@genesis:/home/kirill/workspace/Test2# corebuild hw.native
Finished, 4 targets (0 cached) in 00:00:00.
root@genesis:/home/kirill/workspace/Test2# ./hw.native
1
1
Player 1, enter two numbers: 
root@genesis:/home/kirill/workspace/Test2#
```

Why this code :

```
 let x1 = Scanf.scanf "%i\n" (fun n -> n) in
 let y1 = Scanf.scanf "%i\n" (fun n -> n) in
```

run before this code:

```
   let () = Printf.printf "Player %i, enter two numbers: \n" pl in
```

???

Sorry for bad english. Thank you for your answers!

Comment: It's not the code that is executed out of order, just the printer that did not flush it. Try adding `%!` at the end of the string (or calling `flush stdout`), it should output as expected. Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31216473

Comment: possible duplicate of [OCaml function calls happening in wrong order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31216473/ocaml-function-calls-happening-in-wrong-order)

Answer (score 3):

In all languages buffered IO libraries instead of outputting directly into device, will output first into intermediate buffer. They will flush data as soon as the buffer is full or overflowed. They will also flush data at the exit of your program. Here, data is not flushed (and thus is not printed) until the program is finished. You can use `flush` or `flush_all` function, or use OCaml-specific printf specifier `%!`, to flush data at specific program points, e.g.,

```
Printf.printf "Player %i, enter two numbers: \n%!"
```